# Is it possible to rename the name of a release on Google Play Console after it's been published?

Tags: android, apk, release

I mean renaming the name you choose to be able to distinguish it from other releases from the dev console, not the "official" release name.

Comment: You may want to rephrase the question to - "Is it possible to rename the *name of* a release on Google Play Console after it's been rolled out (or published)

Comment: done. better late than never lol.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Go to `Production` > `Releases` tab > `View release details` > scroll bottom to Release notes, click `edit release details`

Here you can change the release name.

Comment: You have to scroll down- to see 'Edit release details' (beyond deactivated releases). This UI is the worst.